# angular custom directive for class binding

Tags: angular, custom-directive

My directive

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  @Input('highlight') isHighlighted = false;

  constructor() {}

  @HostBinding('class')
  get function () {
    return {
      'highlighted': this.isHighlighted,
      'bordered': this.isHighlighted
    }
  }
}
```

using directive as:

```
<course-card (courseSelected)="onCourseSelected($event)"
             [course]="course"
             [highlight]="highlight">
```

where `highlight is BOOLEAN`

classes are correctly applied in the DOM as:
`class="bordered highlighted"`.

highlighted class has effect but there is no effect for bordered class

style classes are defined as:

```
.highlighted{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}

.bordered {
    border-top: 5px solid lightgreen;
}
```

I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Angular component by default would have display:inline for all component. Due to which the styles are not visible to screen change course component display type to block

**course.component.css**

```
:host { display: block; }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yggk6x?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)